# Turtle Graphics Variable in writing error

Tags: python

While making a simple game using turtle graphics, I have come across an error while trying to display the player's respective health.

Problem is that neither player's health goes below 4, and when the opposite player is hit, the person who was damaged gets their health reset.

I have tried looping but have been unsuccessful when doing so.

I am not quite sure if the problem lies where the 'shoot' functions are but I do think it's highly likely

this is the code for what happens when player 2 is hit, the code is the same for when player 1 is hit so I did not list it

```
import turtle
    import time


    global Player_1, Player_2


    win = turtle.Screen()
    win.title("ShipBattle by@Alex")
    win.bgcolor("lightblue")
    win.setup(width=800, height=600)





pen = turtle.Turtle()


pen.color("black")
pen.pensize(5)
pen.speed(0)


pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0,200)
pen.pendown()

#pen.write("Player 1 HP = " + str(Player_1) + "            " + "Player 2 HP = " + str(Player_2))
Player_1 = 5
Player_2 = 5

pen.write("Player 1 HP =" + str(Player_1) + " Player 2 HP = "+ str(Player_2), align="center", font=("Courier",16,"normal"))




# function setup



def is_collided_with(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 60 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 60



def shoot():
    x = ship_a.xcor()
    y = ship_a.ycor()


    canonball.hideturtle()
    canonball.setpos(x,y)
    canonball.showturtle()
    canonball.speed(1)
    canonball.forward(100)
    canonball.hideturtle()



    if is_collided_with(canonball, ship_b):
            Player_1 = 5
            Player_2 = 5

            print("Collision!")       
            Player_2 -= 1    
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Player 1 HP = "+str(Player_1) +" Player 2 HP = "+ str(Player_2), align="center", font=("Courier",16,"normal"))

            if Player_2 == 0:
                print("Game Over!")
                pen.write("Game Over!")



    else:
        print("That was a miss!")
```

Comment: You are explicitly setting both players' scores to 5 inside `shoot()`, so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: When I take it out of the shoot function I get this error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Player_2' referenced before assignment", Where should I tell it that both players are 5 for it to correctly take their health down to 0? sorry I am not very good with python yet

Comment: Set those two variables globally, outside any function.

Comment: global Player_1

global Player_2

Player_1 = 5
Player_2 = 5

Comment: I set it to that at the very start of the program and I still get the: "local variable 'Player_2' referenced before assignment" error"

Comment: It does mention this is where the problem lies though: "line 164, in shoot
    Player_2 -= 1" hope that helps clear some stuff up

Comment: Oh, I see where i went wrong, I still needed to mention global variable in the shoot function, So sorry for wasting your time.